# How to edit/write back a JSON file hosted on a localhost using XMLHttpRequest() post method

Tags: javascript, json, post, xmlhttprequest

I am able to use the `XMLHttpRequest()` `GET` method to retrieve the data from the `.json` file, but when I try to use POST to update it, I receive a `404` error (Even though I can access the json file by simply typing in `localhost:8080\data.json`

I'm not sure why this is happening. The error is shown below:
`POST` `http://localhost:8080/data.json` 404 (Not Found)

I'm hosting the main html, and js files using node.js and express. I'm also using sockets to connect between the client side and server side. I've shown the two functions- the `GET` which works perfectly fine, and the POST which is not working.

I'm wondering whether it is a permissions or browser security issue? (I'm using chrome)

```
function init(){
var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
xobj.open("GET","data.json");
xobj.onload = function(){
    if(xobj.status===200 && xobj.readyState ===4){
        person = JSON.parse(xobj.responseText); 
        if(person){//not sure if this check helps
            for(var i=0;i<person.things.length;i++){
                place.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',"<p>"+  person.things[i].text +"</p>");
            }
        }
    }else{
        console.log("error getting data");
    }
}
xobj.send();
}

function sendDataToFile(data){
console.log(data);
//write to data.json
var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();

xobj.open("POST","data.json",true);
xobj.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xobj.onload = function(){
    if(xobj.status===200 && xobj.readyState ===4){

    }else{
        console.log("error getting data");
    }

}
person.things.push({text:data}); //pushing new data
var sendString = JSON.stringify(person);//convert to json object
console.log(sendString);
xobj.send(sendString); //send
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: You can't `post` to a local file.

Comment: you can't post directly to any file, you post to something that processes the post request and writes the file for you - what server side system are you using? php? node? asp? python? something else?

Comment: imagine if posting like that actually worked!! You could use any server on the internet to host your own files, overwrite web pages with your own code ... the world wide web would be dead within an hour!

Comment: I'm using node as the server side.

Comment: Is it then  all i have to do is add a function in my server.js that handles the post request and writes to the file?

Comment: and send my post request to the localhost?